# jQuery Mobile avoid changePage() in ajax form submit

Tags: ajax, forms, jquery-mobile

I have a `post` form, I want the `submit` to be done in an *AJAX* way but I don't want the page URL to change.

For example:

```
<form action="/countries/change_country" data-ajax="true" method="post">
  <select name="country_code">
    <option value="FR" selected="selected">France</option>
    <option value="DE">Germany</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="change country" />
</form>
```

When I click in the `change country` button the form is sent through AJAX what is nice but the page URL is changed to `/countries/change_country` what is not nice because this URL doesn't exist in my server which is very *picky* with HTTP verbs.

I know it is possible to change this default behavior for the whole application but I would like to deactivate the `changePage()` only for this form.

Comment: You want the user to stay on the same page after submitting the form?

Comment: Try this, I hope it works ` $("form").on("submit", function(){
      $("form").attr("action", "/countries/change_country");
      $.mobile.changePage("#YourPageID", { allowSamePageTransition : true });
     });`

Comment: try `data-ajax="false"` on form and do the submission via ajax with code

Comment: @OmarNew2PHP I want the page to change (through AJAX) but at the same time I want the URL to *not* change.

Comment: @OmarNew2PHP yes I can try several hacks but I'm looking for a clean out-of-the-box solution, something like `<form data-ajax="true" data-push-state="false">`. If I need to start playing with hacks I will just not using the jQuery Mobil AJAX form and do the AJAX submit by myself.

Comment: @Mithun this is not what I'm looking, I actually want the form to be submitted through AJAX.

Comment: Have you tried `event.preventDefault()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Submit the form through **Javascript/jQuery** instead.

*First*: **Disable** the default submit-behaviour

```
$('#form').on('submit', function (e) {
   if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
   return false;
});
```

*Second*: **Serialize** the form data with jQuery

```
var serializedFormData = $('#form').serialize();
```

*Third*: **Post** your form with `$.ajax();`

```
$.ajax({
   url: '/countries/change_country',
   type: 'POST',
   data: serializedFormData
});
```

Comment: I was looking for a "jQuery Mobile out-of-the-box" solution, but I see I have to use my own mechanism as the one you propose.

Comment: I was looking for the same as you, but I didn't find any "out-of-the-box" solutions. This was the best I found.